# How to remove the type errors in angular2 forms

Tags: angular

I get the following error in my commond prompt `property 'controls' doesnot exist on type 'AbstractControl'`...I application works fine but i want to remove such kind of errors.I get such kind of erros when i have statements like `this.PaymentsForm.controls['CustPayment'].controls['Parts'].value;` where `PaymentsForm`and `CustPayment`are formgroups and `Parts`is an formControl.Can somebody please help me how to eliminate such kind of type errors.

Comment: could you please share your component and its html code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get()` is preferred

```
this.PaymentForm.get('CustomPayment.Parts').value
```

or

```
this.PaymentForm.get(['CustomPayment', 'Parts']).value
```

It seems now only `FormGroup` and `FormArray` provide the `controls` property.

If you know the element is one, you can cast like

```
(<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>this.PaymentsForm).controls['CustPayment']).controls['Parts'].value;
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor